# Как создать кнопки видимые только админу? Telegram.bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Например, возьмем кнопку со статистикой (какие пользователи вошли в систему и когда) эта кнопка не должна быть видна обычным пользователям.

Comment: включай эту опцию для пользователя который введет специальную команду например /displayHiddenButtons или же задай вручную у себя в коде айдишник пользователя которому должны показываться доп.кнопки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализовал так:

```
if (userId == тут ID)
        {
            ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                new KeyboardButton[]{"Кнопка"},
            })
            {
                ResizeKeyboard = true
            };
            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                chatId: chatId,
                text: "Choose",
                replyMarkup: keyboard);
        }
```

Comment: Как иногда пишут в этих самых интернетах - "кросавчег!" - встретился с проблемой, сам разобрался, да еще и для других описал решение.

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: @S.H. угу, "сам разобрался" по моему комментарию))) Но, в принципе, все равно молодец)